# Xen boot fails on HP Z8

Tags: virtualization, xen

I followed the instructions in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xen.
Well, the first two steps.  After the reboot, I am presented with:

```
Loading Xen 4.9-amd_64 ...
WARNING: no console will be available to OS
Loading Linux 4.15.0-20-generic ...
Loading initial ramdisk ...
```

Nothing more.

Does anyone run Ubuntu as dom0 in Xen these days?
This is on a new HP Z8 workstation with dual "silver xeon 4114" which should have all the requisite functions.

I am a bit concerned about the lack of much detail in the BIOS.  About the only thing I can tweak is the Hyper-threading setting.

Comment: I did eventually stumble in the BIOS settings page to enable all the requisite hypervisor settings: hidden under "security" TAB.  Unfortunately, the boot still failed in the same manner, so I have given up on trying to get this to work for now.  XenServer did install and run, and Qubes-OS is running, so ubuntu should run as dom0.

Comment: Having the same problem and not solution yet, but it is helpful to add this to <code>/etc/default/grub</code>: 'GRUB_CMDLINE_XEN="noreboot". This stops the system to reboot after Xen fails. I did get error messages displayed I did not see before. Only disadvantage: you need to reboot manually.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar problems with an ASUS PRIME-B250M-C/CSM motherboard.  I tweaked the UEFI settings:
        disable FastBoot
        enable CSM (compatibility support mode)
and then the system pauses after the above boot messages, but then gets Ubuntu-18.04 server started.

Also, note that the Xen kernel does not expose EFI variables to Dom0, so **efibootmgr**(8) fails.